# How to use SQL CONCAT/SUBSTR?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, substr

I am trying to create a username for each person in the marketing table.
I want an update statement that inserts the new username into the username column.

I want to take the first letter of the firstname, join to the first 5 letters of the surname, and save this into the username column of the marketing table. I need to put this inside a procedure somehow too.

heres my code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.firstname, 1)||SUBSTR(m.surname, 5)
INTO username
FROM marketing
WHERE marketing_id = 10001;
```

However, I am getting errors that I cannot seem to fix, like firstname and surname are invalid identifiers. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: What do you do when you have users `Paul Jones` and `Peter Jones`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
update username
set username= (select concat(left(firstname,1),left(surname,5))
                  from marketing
                  WHERE marketing_id = 10001)
WHERE marketing_id = 10001;
```

Comment: UPDATE TABLE marketing or UPDATE marketing? as it says missing expression :/

Comment: it not working, still missing expression
    UPDATE username
    SET username = SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(firstname,1),LEFT(surname,5))
    FROM marketing
    WHERE marketing_id = 10001;

Comment: try above query which was updated. In previous pranthesis is missing and some where cond'n...sorry

Comment: As well as the wrong table name, you have an extra semicolon in the subquery, you don't need a subquery if it's updating the same table, and more importantly Oracle doesn't have a `left()` function.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing the `concat` function, `substr` function and the concatentation operator (`||`). You aren't using `substr` to get the first character of the first name, and to restirct the length of both you need to provide [both the starting position and the substring length](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions181.htm).

You're also referring to `m.firstname` without defining `m` as an alias for your table name; an alias isn't really needed here as there is only one table but if you use it, use it consistently.

To get the first letter of the firstname and the first five letters of the surname you could use:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(m.firstname, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(m.surname, 1, 5)
FROM marketing m
WHERE m.marketing_id = 10001;
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(m.firstname, 1, 1), SUBSTR(m.surname, 1, 5))
FROM marketing m
WHERE m.marketing_id = 10001;
```

If you're updating a column in the same table though, rather than using a PL/SQL `into` clause, you need an update not a select:

```
UPDATE marketing
SET username = SUBSTR(firstname, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(surname, 1, 5)
WHERE marketing_id = 10001;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2191f/1).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's finally working and I understand where I was going wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to put this into a procedure, but i am now getting errors when i try to execute it, saying invalid SQL statement, any advice?



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_create_username(vn_marketing_id marketing.marketing_id%TYPE) IS

    BEGIN
     UPDATE marketing
     SET username = SUBSTR(firstname, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(surname, 1, 5)
     WHERE marketing_id = vn_marketing_id;
END proc_create_username;
/
EXECUTE proc_create_username(10002); '

Comment: @ChantelleL - that's valid if it's formatted right, and if your client is letting you run multiple statements. Are you running those two commands as a single statement, separate statements, or as a script? Is the procedure being created? Which client are you using - does it understand `execute`?

Comment: @OP, this is indeed a complete answer. You should mark it as answered.

Comment: The procedure is being created, but when i run the execution statement, I get:ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: @ChantelleL - then maybe your client doesn't understand `execute`; try with an explicit anonymous block, e.g. `begin proc_create_username(10002); end;`. As Lalit hinted, this is moving into a different question really.

Answer (score 1):

The `m` in `m.name` needs to have been defined, that's missing. `CONCAT` (MySQL?) should consume strings, you pass a number (`1`) in addition to a string. Your description mentions two substrings, the statement has just one, measured by occurrences of `SUBSTR`. The concatenation operator, if supported by your dialect of SQL, will then not see what you intended it to see (two `SUBSTR`ings).